# How to disable MapsGL in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

I clicked on the "Try MapsGL" button in Google Maps. After trying it, I decide, that I want to go back to old maps, as they require less resources on my old PC. But the button to switch back is nowhere to be found. 
How do I go back to old maps?

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add `vector=0` to the end of your URL string parameters. 
So your maps URL would be `http://maps.google.com/?vector=0`. This will tell the maps not to use MapsGL.

Alternatively, if you want to switch back to MapsGL, put `vector=1` in your URL.